# Get test ether in parity account

Tags: parity, testnets, json-rpc, testrpc, parity-signer

I installed parity-poa-playground from (https://github.com/dstarcev/parity-poa-playground) on Windows 10 and managed to made it working with parity configured from (https://github.com/paritytech/parity).

Now, after compilation when i run `cargo run --release` I think it start mining real ether. but i want development ether in my account.

If I made transaction using following

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x6B0c56d1Ad5144b4d37fa6e27DC9afd5C2435c3B","to":"0x00f3409AF27Eaa81CbF5d2884d8c138cD633826d","value":"0x186a0"}, ""],"id":0}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 192.168.99.100:8545
```

where `0x00f3409AF27Eaa81CbF5d2884d8c138cD633826d` is my account in parity, it gives me the following output:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x8744eab96a01dcfeda3e674f94de0851aff1d6b7d8ee6b08aea15b460f5af0e9","id":0}
```

but no change in my account in parity.